# Why does MR_save not work but MR_saveNestedContexts does?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to persist an managed object called "Me". Here is the two methods I'm trying (the first method doesn't persist the data but the second one does):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
[Me MR_createInContext:localContext];
[localContext MR_save];
```

The above method does not persist the data but the below one does:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
[Me MR_createInContext:localContext];
[localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];
```

Why is MR_save not working?

Comment: Refer to ["Regarding MagicalRecord, what is the difference between the methods MR_saveNestedContexts and MR_save"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300129/regarding-magicalrecord-what-is-the-difference-between-the-methods-mr-saveneste/13344324#13344324).  There is a good description between the two methods.

Comment: So is it important to call both MR_save AND MR_saveNestedContexts every time a new entity is stores?

Comment: Well as of version 2.0.8, if you want to make sure you persist your nested contexts to the store, use `MR_saveNestedContexts`. If you want to save up **ONLY ONE** parent, use `MR_save`. **IF** the parent happens to be the root/default context, `MR_saveNestedContexts` and `MR_save` do the same thing, which is to persist to store.

Comment: If you add your comments to an answer, I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

Refer to ["Regarding MagicalRecord, what is the difference between the methods MR_saveNestedContexts and MR_save"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300129/regarding-magicalrecord-what-is-the-difference-between-the-methods-mr-saveneste). There is a good description between the two methods.

As of version 2.0.8, if you want to make sure you persist your nested contexts to the store, use `MR_saveNestedContexts`. If you want to save up **ONLY ONE** parent, use `MR_save`. **IF** the parent happens to be the root/default context, `MR_saveNestedContexts` and `MR_save` do the same thing, which is to persist to store.